# How we put style sheet in head tag in objective c

Tags: html, ios, objective-c, regex, ios8

I want to insert style tag in to html. MY style tag is finalstyle i want to insert insert in mailbody head . This code not work for me. The final style not embeded.

this my style

```
$1<div ><style type="text/css"> p.p1 {margin: 0.0px 0.0px 0.0px 0.0px; font: 15.0px 'Helvetica Neue'} span.s1 {font-family: 'Helvetica Neue'; font-weight: bold; font-style: normal; font-size: 15.00px; text-decoration: underline} </style></div><br /><div style="border-left: 1px solid grey; padding-left: 15px"> –



replacements = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"$1<div>%@</div><br /><div style=\"border-left: 1px solid grey; padding-left: 15px\">", finalstyle]; 

 NSRegularExpression *regexs = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"(<head.*?>)" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:&error];
            mailBody = [regexs stringByReplacingMatchesInString:mailBody options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [mailBody length]) withTemplate:replacements];;
```

Comment: you kept %@ after <div> you should kept it in <div %@>.do you want to add style as attribute or as starting and closing tags?

Comment: i want insert replacement styletag in head of html. it insert right way but the font-weight not shown

Comment: can you share css which you are inserting

Comment: $1<div ><style type="text/css">
p.p1 {margin: 0.0px 0.0px 0.0px 0.0px; font: 15.0px 'Helvetica Neue'}
span.s1 {font-family: 'Helvetica Neue'; font-weight: bold; font-style: normal; font-size: 15.00px; text-decoration: underline}
</style></div><br /><div style="border-left: 1px solid grey; padding-left: 15px">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NSRegularExpression *regexs = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"(<p class=\"p2\".*?>)" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:&error];
                mailBody = [regexs stringByReplacingMatchesInString:mailBody options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [mailBody length]) withTemplate:replacements];;
        NSLog(@"%@",mailBody);
```

Answer (score 0):

it is working.

```
NSString *fileStyle=@"<style type=\"text/css\"> p.p1 {margin: 0.0px 0.0px 0.0px 0.0px; font: 25.0px 'Helvetica Neue'} span.s1 {font-family: 'Helvetica Neue'; font-weight: bold; font-style: normal; font-size: 15.00px; text-decoration: underline} </style>";

NSString *emailBody = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html><head>%@</head><body><p class=\"p1\">sesfes</p></body></html>", fileStyle];
```